# Fancy indexing with portion of string in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas DataFrame that looks something like this:

```
  Loc WT Var  Change AO     DP    VAF IntEx    Upstream  Downstream Individual
  0  10  A   T  C>T  40  30000  0.003  Exon  ATGCTCGTAG  AGTCGATCGT          1
  1  10  A   T  C>T  40  30000  0.003  Exon  ATGCTCGTAG  AGTCGATCGT          1
  2  10  A   T  C>T  40  30000  0.003  Exon  ATGCTCGTAG  AGTCGATCGT          1
  3  10  A   T  C>T  40  30000  0.003  Exon  ATGCTCGTAG  AGTCGATCGT          1
```

And I am trying to select a portion of the DataFrame in which the first letter of the string within the 'Downstream' column is a particular letter but I'm getting a key error when trying to do that with something like the following:

```
a = allVariants[allVariants['Downstream'[0] == 'G']]
```

Comment: Use `df[df.Downstream.str[0].eq('G')]`.

Comment: Fancy indexing is probably the wrong term here.

Comment: you can use `str.startswith`, e.g. `allVariants.Downstream.str.startswith('G')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The condition you're looking for is -

```
df[df.Downstream.str[0].eq('G')]
```

Or,

```
df[df.Downstream.str.startswith('G')]
```

---

Sample data -

```
df

   Loc WT Var Change  AO     DP    VAF IntEx    Upstream  Downstream  \
0   10  A   T    C>T  40  30000  0.003  Exon  ATGCTCGTAG  AGTCGATCGT   
1   10  A   T    C>T  40  30000  0.003  Exon  ATGCTCGTAG  AGTCGATCGT   
2   10  A   T    C>T  40  30000  0.003  Exon  ATGCTCGTAG  GTCGATCGTA   
3   10  A   T    C>T  40  30000  0.003  Exon  ATGCTCGTAG  GTCGATCGTA   

   Individual  
0           1  
1           1  
2           1  
3           1
```

```
df[df.Downstream.str[0].eq('G')]

   Loc WT Var Change  AO     DP    VAF IntEx    Upstream  Downstream  \
2   10  A   T    C>T  40  30000  0.003  Exon  ATGCTCGTAG  GTCGATCGTA   
3   10  A   T    C>T  40  30000  0.003  Exon  ATGCTCGTAG  GTCGATCGTA   

   Individual  
2           1  
3           1
```

How it works -

1. `Downstream` is a string column. You can access the first character using the `.str` accessor - `df.Downstream.str[0]`.
2. Compare this value with `'G'` using `eq` or `==` to get a boolean mask.
3. Finally index into `df` with the mask.

Alternatively, calling `.str.startswith` will compare the first character with the character passed (`'G'`) to return a boolean mask similar to the first case.